# When working with a settings directory, where should I import it?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have recently started working with a settings directory as described in the *Two Scoops of Django* book. It contains the following files

- `local.py`
- `staging.py`
- `production.py`
- `test.py`
- `__init__.py`

To be able to use the different setting files on the server I have adapted my django.fcgi script to import the settings module. It works very smoothly.

How do I do the same on my local machine on which I use runserver, however? I have set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and I have adapted the `manage.py` file to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
import imp

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/don.joey/projects/a_project/a_project_site/settings')

import settings

try:
    imp.find_module('settings') # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings)
```

It works fine.

**How can I make `django-admin.py` find these settings?** I do not want to manually edit django-admin.py because it is part of my virtualenv and it will does thus regularly be updated.

## Update

I have set the following: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.local`.

Comment: Why not have the virtualenv start script set `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `settings.whatever`?

Comment: Have you add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to your `env` AND the project root to your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @bnjmn I have set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, but I have no idea where to set the pythonpath for the project root. Is that in my venv?

Comment: Add it to your shell env, if that's where you are using `django-admin.py`, something like `export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/don.joey/projects/a_project/a_project_site:PYTHONPATH`

Comment: It should be the directory where the actual `project_root` is. It should be wherever the `manage.py` file is.

Comment: @bnjmn Thanks for your help. I think we are almost there. I have tried running the command `PYTHONPATH=/home/user/don.joey/projects/a_project/a_project_site/ django-admin.py shell` but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set two things

- `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and
- `PYTHONPATH` so that the settings module can be found

The way *Two Scoops of Django* suggests setting up a project named `blah` you would have the following directory structure:

```
- blah_project/
    - blah/
        - manage.py
        - blah/
            - ...
            - settings/
                 - __init__.py
                 - local.py
                 - production.py
                 - ...
```

Run the following (assuming a `bash` environment):

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=blah.settings.local
export PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/blah_project/blah
```

As long as `django-admin.py` is on your path (and it should be if `django` is installed and activated within your `venv`), you should be able to run:

```
django-admin.py runserver
```

Comment: This may not be exactly what you are used to if you are using `./manage.py` to run your commands but it may work a little better actually. You can then easily switch settings by simply change the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. This makes (staging|production) deployment much easier. Also, no need to edit `manage.py`.

Comment: This if nice and it works. One more thing: could you add something on how to set these variables automatically when activating a venv?

Comment: Glad to hear it. I can add that. If the answer solved your problem Could you up vote ;)? Are you using `virtualenv-wrapper` by any chance? It makes that process pretty simple through a `postactivate` hook. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11134336/770019

Comment: Done. I'll look into the link of your comment. Thakns