# New environment varibles does not show up in django app

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have added some new environment variables to my virtualenv.
Added:

```
export BROKER_URL='amqp://guest:guest@localhost/prod'
```

to my bin/activate file.

But reloading uswgi does not make the new variables show up in my django app where I try and get it with:

```
BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('BROKER_URL')
```

Comment: Where did you add the environment variables? Is it in `postactivate` script?

Comment: In the bin/activate file

Comment: I think you are not supposed to edit `bin/activate`. The hook `bin/postactivate` is executed after `bin/activate`. I have all my environment variables in this file.

Comment: Just tried moving them, but it is still not working. Still not picking up the new environment varibles

Comment: Does it work when you activate the environment from the console? `unset BROKER_URL; source bin/activate; echo $BROKER_URL`

Comment: Forget what is said about `postactivate`, I think it is only part of virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554087/setting-an-environment-variable-in-virtualenv

Comment: That wasn't it. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that uwsgi does not pick up variables in the activate file. Guess it is not using it when run by supervisor

Solution is to add the environment variable to the uwsgi ini file like so:

```
env = BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@localhost/prod
```