# How do I use variables created in venv bash in my django app?

Tags: django, bash, heroku, environment-variables, development-environment

If I create a variable in my venv like this

```
DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=local
```

and on heroku I have

```
DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=production
```

why won't my system recognize this

```
from .base import *
import os
if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'local':
    try:
        from .local import *
    except:
        pass

if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'production':
    try:
        from .production import *
    except:
        pass
```

I keep getting this error

```
File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/gettingstarted/settings/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'local':
    File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/bin/../lib/python3.5/os.py", line 683, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'
```

How do I use the local variable that I created?

Comment: I don't know much about heroku, but if `DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=production` is your setting, you might want to try `export DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=production`. `export` would make the env variable available across all sessions.

Comment: @ShangWangthanks but that's not the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your environment variable does NOT exist locally. There are a lot of ways to set environment variables locally.

I highly recommend using the [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) written by Kenneth Reitz. This is a cool tool you can install locally on your computer. See [setting an environment variable in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554087/setting-an-environment-variable-in-virtualenv) for more information.

The way it works is that you define a file called `.env` in your project directory, and list all of your environment variables inside of it. For instance:

```
export DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=local
```

Everytime you enter that directory on the command line (like `cd ~/my_project`), autoenv will automatically set whatever environment variables you've got in that folder as active. It's very useful.

Anyhow, wherever you're currently storing your environment variables, you'll need to `export` them if you don't want to use something like autoenv.

So, let's say you've got a file (`env.sh`) that has your environment variables defined in it like so:

```
DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=local
```

You can 'run' this file by saying `sh env.sh`. Now, you might expect that this would run, and you would now have `DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE` defined in your environment variables, right?

Well, not exactly.

In `sh` (the scripting language you're actually using here), you need to put the `export` keyword in front of a variable if you want the variable to be exported OUTSIDE of the running script.

So, in order to actually set your variable, you would have to say:

```
export DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=local
```

Then run that file as a script: `sh env.sh`. If you do that, you'll notice that now your environment variable IS actually set.

Another useful thing to know while testing this out, is that if you run the `env` command on the command line, it will output a list of all environment variables currently set LOCALLY. This is useful for debugging, eg:

```
env | grep DJANGO_
```

Comment: rdegges it is on my heroku app. It stated that above. But thanks for the response

Comment: Sorry @nothingness, misread your question. I just updated my answer to reflect it =)