# How to choose Django config setting in virtualenv just once

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I was reading some materials to better organize my code in Django and I started reading this: http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/ ... Thought it was a good idea to have different config-settings for `production` and `development`, mostly because of databases.

After that in the post it's explained that we can do one of two things to select the config-setting we want:

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="foo.settings.production"` 
or

`./manage.py migrate —settings=foo.settings.development`

And I thought the first option is better... so every time I initialize my virtualenv, before I run `python manage.py runserver` I need do: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="foo.settings.development"`...

Hmm, I believe if I edit my `~/.bashrc` and include `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="foo.settings.development"` I won't have to do it again. But this will shared across all my virtualenvs and I don't want this.

To summarize: I want to define `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="foo.settings.development"` just once in my virtualenv and to keep it there. Independently (that's the point of virtualenvs, right)...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11134336/626613

Comment: Thank you a lot! @hsen ... If you write an answer I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using virtualenvwrapper, you can put it in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate` script. like

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='foo.settings.development'`

In the same script you can see a deactivate function, there you can unset the environment variable, which will be called while deactivating virtualenv

`unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

If you are using virtualenvwrapper you can set environment variable in `postactivate` and unset it in `postdeactivate` scripts