# Running script in bash from a virtualenv

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I am trying to run script in bash from python, but I am currently working in a virtualenv, and when my script calls on a specific program, I get "usr/bin/env: luajit: No such file or directory".

When I run the same script inside a separate bash window (outside the virtualenv), it runs perfectly.

I have a feeling it is because this program is not properly being pointed to, but have no idea how to tell my virtualenv to look for that program.. How do I get around this?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, using python 2

Comment: I should mention that when running the exact same python script from outside my virtualenv, everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in environment variables. `PATH` should contain the location where your `luajit` is.

See [setting an environment variable in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554087/setting-an-environment-variable-in-virtualenv) for some ways to automatically set environment variables in a virtualenv (but two of the currently suggested ways require wrappers and one - editing a stock script). [There's no magic: virtualenv edition by Allison Kaptur](https://www.recurse.com/blog/14-there-is-no-magic-virtualenv-edition) describes the (rather simple) magic behind virtualenv's work so you may be able to find an even better place to put the variable assignment in.