# Needing to Reset Environment Variables in VirtualEnv Session

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, command-prompt, slack

I am working on a Slack Bot and mostly followed this [tutorial](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/build-first-slack-bot-python.html), except for some things that were different on Windows. One of these was setting the BOT_ID and SLACK_BOT_TOKEN environment variables. I used `set BOT_ID=xcdsfsdf` in a command prompt that was in a virtualenv session. Now that I've closed everything and returned to the project, BOT_ID and SLACK_BOT_TOKEN were no longer variables.

How can I set these variables so that I do not have to re-create them each time?

I could simply add these as system variables, but what if I was creating multiple slack bots? What is the standard practice? SLACK_BOT_TOKEN_1, SLACK_BOT_TOKEN_2, etc?

Additionally, when I go to reopen the project to run the python code, do I need to activate the virtualenv each time? Or can I just execute the python code?

Comment: In your virtual environment, usully in `bin` there should be a couple of script like `post_activate` where you can put that.

Comment: I'm running virtualenv on windows. There is no `bin`, just a Scripts folder where the activate.bat file was. I don't see any post-activate script. There is a deactivate.bat file.

Comment: The put it at the end of `activate.bat`.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that as opposed to just putting the API token and ID in the python code? I thought this was to avoid having the token in plain text in a file for security?

Comment: You have two options: store it or enter it every time. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .env file in the root directory of your virtualenv and store your variables. I use it for django in this manner:

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='some_password'
DJANGO_DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY='a_complex_key'
```

Comment: Are .env files for Linux? I tried creating one, but it didn't work. I forced the extension to be .env and it wasn't recognized. I can just put the environment variables directly in the batch file.

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work. The batch file ran the activate.bat for virtualenv and didn't set the variables.

Comment: I use it on linux and mac, but I read that it can be used on Windows too. That is why I posted.

Comment: I suggest trying this package top help, https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv

Answer (score 1):

The solution described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20918496/8298629) worked for me. Add the export lines to your bin/activate file.