# Setting debian environment variables for use in a web application and by command line users

Tags: python, environment-variables, debian

I'm trying to move some of the config out of my python web applications into the environment, and I'm wondering if there's a best practice for making environment variables available to **all** users.

For example, I'm setting the env variable `PYTHON_MSSQL_DRIVER="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"`, and I want it to be available to www-data (the user that nginx and uwsgi use to serve the applications),   But I also want the env variable available to any developer who might be running a python script on command line (or the automated tests), so simply `sudo -u www-data export...` won't do the trick.

Comment: You are using python (according tag), so you should use virtual environments, and soI would redirect you to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554087/setting-an-environment-variable-in-virtualenv . An other way I use: set sourced scripts which set env, but also colour of prompt (so you know where you are), e.g. also devel, test, deploy specific script and variables. Check `sudo` doc on how to keep some env variables (and possibly improve your deployment script).

Comment: unfortunately, virtual environments aren't going to work (the stack just wasn't setup that way)

Comment: What about using a launcher? Instead of true program, export set variables and call the true program?